# Is it possible to hook up an external mic to a Nikon D90 to get better sound for video?

Tags: video

I'm getting bad sound quality on video taken with my NIKON D90. I think the mic is bad so I need to know if it is possible to plug a microphone into it some how?

Comment: Cant you get a usb attachment for male end on a mic

Answer (score 9):

Nope, it sure doesn't.  On that camera, its only got an internal mic.  Your options are:

- Record sound otherwise and then sync up in post.
- Buy a new camera like a D7000 that will take an external mic.
- Use an actual video camera that takes an external mic.
- Possibly tape some material to mimic a windscreen over the existing D90 mic, to help *a little* in some situations.
- Live with the limitation.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot plug in a microphone into the D90. There really isn't.

I would recommend you to buy a Zoom H1 which is a separate sound recording device that records sound onto SD cards. It is rather cheap, but has much, much better sound quality than the D90's built in microphone. Actually it' much better than the D7000's build in microphone as well. It is very easy to synchronize the video with the separately recorded sound. This is the way the professionals do it. Check out YouTube on how to synchronize video and sound in any program of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it can't.
If you can't afford buying another camera as suggested...getting an iSK CM-20 Super condenser mic and recording sound externally with it will give you a great sound plus it's an affordable solution. You will have to sync up the sound on post production.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Mini USB port available on D90. Use a Mini USB to 3.5 audio connector and plug in the external mic to it.

Should work. Give it a try.